# How to forbid non https traffic in my android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, https

How should I setup my manifest and network_security_config.xml file (and other files?) to forbid http traffic ? I want to allow only https traffic (I use many https APIs from third party providers, but no http APIs ; for security reasons, I want to make http connections impossible).

Thanks

Comment: http traffic is default impossible, blocked. Only when you mess around with clear text traffic or network config you can allow it.

Comment: Thanks. It is the feeling I had, but was not sure. Thanks.

Comment: clear text traffic is blocked by default only on Android 9 or higher, so you still might want to configure old Android version to block it. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted